# Angular 2, checkbox two-way model binding, dom not reflecting checked status on manipulation of the state from within a component

Tags: angular

Per [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Iv79DZbNnVudKWyINcdB)

I have a series of checkboxes:

```ts
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" [(ngModel)]="foo" (change)="changed()">Foo</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="bar" [(ngModel)]="bar" (change)="changed()">Bar</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="baz" [(ngModel)]="baz" (change)="changed()">Baz</label>
```

On checking all three checkboxes, they should all revert to unchecked:

```ts
changed() {
  if (this.foo && this.bar && this.baz) {
    this.foo = false;
    this.bar = false;
    this.baz = false;
  }

  console.log(`foo: ${this.foo};bar: ${this.bar};baz: ${this.baz}`)
}
```

Instead what I see is that first time around it seems to work, but subsequently, on checking the third checkbox, the model updates to false, however the checkbox remains checked in the UI, becoming out of sync.

For now I have fixed it by passing in the event and toggling the checked state of the target dom element myself. But I wonder how it can become out of sync in the first place? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is `false` and you click the checkbox to change the value to `true` and the event handler changes it back to `false`, then Angular change detection doesn't see a change and doesn't update bindings (the checkbox keeps its `true` value though).

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

changed() {
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  if (this.foo && this.bar && this.baz) {
    this.foo = false;
    this.bar = false;
    this.baz = false;
  }
  console.log(`foo: ${this.foo};bar: ${this.bar};baz: ${this.baz}`)
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rShLcigdC4ujUiXMdEQM?p=preview)